# Change background of a Control in a MultiDataTrigger Condition based on parent property

Tags: wpf

I try to set my `Button`s' background differently based on the `IsSelected` property of their parent control.
What I currently have:
I have a `ListBoxItem`, which contains a `ContentControl` which contains a `Button` (or more). I would like to set the `Button`'s background based on the `ListBoxItem`'s `IsSelected` property.

This is the code I thought would be good:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="DefaultOperationsField" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Button
                Grid.Column="1"
                Style="{StaticResource DiscardButtonStyle}"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="5"
                Command="{Binding DiscardFixtureChangesCommand}"
                ToolTip="Discard changes">
            </Button>
        </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
    ...
    <ContentControl x:Name="Operations" Content="{Binding}" Template="{StaticResource DefaultOperationsField}"/>
    ...
</ControlTemplate>
```

And I have the stlye for the `Button`:

```
<Style x:Key="DiscardButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="border" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="3">
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource Discard}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="7"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="True" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource FixtureListItemBackgroundBrush}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="False" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ApplicationSelectionBorderBrush}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

However this causes a runtime error with the following message:

```
InvalidOperationException: Must have non-null value for 'Binding'.
```

How can I change background of the `Button` based on ancestral control's property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out if you are using `MultiDataTrigger`s each of your `Condition` must have a value associated to the `Binding` property. In my case here I opt the `Binding` property out for the first `Condition`:

```
<MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
  <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
  <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="True" />
</MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
```

Hence the `NullreferenceException`.
If you want to bind to your normal property - like you do in normal cases, like:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
```

It won't work in case of using `MultiDataTrigger`s. Just change the `Trigger` part here to `Condition` and the `Property` to a proper `Binding` and it will work. In my case this worked perfectly fine:

```
<MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
  <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=border}" Value="True" />
  <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="True" />
</MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
```